# Want to add a same paragraph of text in multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a HTML5/CSS3 website and there is a same block of text in all 10 or 15 webpages. What is best approach to add same text in all webpages?
Should i include that text from an external file through php or javasript?
Or i just copy and paste that text in all web pages?

If i should go with 1st option then will it slow down my website (a little bit) to load an external file?

If i should go with second option then what if the website owner want some changes in that text?

Edited: I already included header,footer and main menu from external files using java. Will it matter to add too many external files in a page?

I preferred java over php because i don't want to change file extension from .html to .php.

Comment: If you use JS, search engines or people without JS won't see it.

Comment: I don't speak PHP but if this was ASP.NET MVC you would likely just create a partial view or a layout file (master page) that includes the repeated text. You probably want to search for PHP "partial view" or "your php framework partial view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i include that text from an external file through php or javasript?

If doing it with PHP is an option, go with that. The fewer HTTP requests the browser has to make to display the page, the better. Also note that while search engines like Google do process *some* JavaScript, I wouldn't rely on them to process an ajax request and index the result. And that ~2% of users who don't have JavaScript enabled won't see the content if you include it with JS. Including it with PHP means you have the content in one file, so updating it is easy (rather than having to update it in the 10 or 15 different places).

More from the [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html):

> **Minimize HTTP Requests**
>
> 80% of the end-user response time is spent on the front-end. Most of this time is tied up in downloading all the components in the page: images, stylesheets, scripts, Flash, etc. Reducing the number of components in turn reduces the number of HTTP requests required to render the page. This is the key to faster pages.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `script` tag in your web-pages (whereever you want this paragraph)

```
<script src="addparagraph.js"></script>
```

in this `addparagraph.js` file

```
(function(){

   var body = document.body;
   body.append( "<p>some text</p>" );  //this paragraph will be appended to every webpage in which add addparagraph.js is loaded

})();
```

this way your owner can always edit changes at one place and this will also be asynchronous so your website will also not slow down

Comment: @user1815004 did you tried this option?

Comment: yeah i tried and it worked. I knew all these methods to include text from external files. My question was which one is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely easiest is to use PHP:

```
<?php include('paragraph.html'); ?>
```

Your page will need to change extension to `.php` for this to work; you also need to have PHP enabled in your web server. There will be a slight performance hit, but it should be so tiny that it won't matter unless you're Google.

Another way to do it is to use a server-side templating engine like Jekyll to generate your 15 HTML files all with the same piece of content. It requires you to recompile your site each time you change something, but it can be automated - and then there is no performance hit at all at serve time.

As you said, the copy-paste solution is the worst, which you should never ever use, even if the customer swears they will never need to edit the pages. Because they eventually always will.